# What’s wrong with my implementation of the power function?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote a code for a simple problem in leetcode. It asks to implement pow(x,n); It tells me that "run time error", Last executed input: 1.00000, -2147483648.  I changed to another method, that works. But I just want to know what I am doing wrong in the following code. Thanks very much!!

```
class Solution {
public:
    double pow(double x, int n) {
        // IMPORTANT: Please reset any member data you declared, as
        // the same Solution instance will be reused for each test case.
        if(n==0 && x==0) return 1.0;
        if(x==0) return 0;
        if(n==0) return 1.0;
        if(n<0) return 1/pow(x,-n);
        if(n==1) return x;

        double y=pow(x,n/2);
        if(n%2==1) return y*y*x;
        else return y*y;

}
```

};

Comment: You are asking for `-n` as an integer when that number (`-(-2147483648)`) cannot be represented in that data type. The result is undefined behavior. Test for the size of `n` at the start of the function.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `int` is 32 bits in length, `-2147483648` is the one unique value, other than 0, in which its negation is equal to itself. So the line:

```
if(n<0) return 1/pow(x,-n);
```

is calling itself with the same parameters, and does so until there is a stack overflow.

In greater detail, the binary representation of -2147483648 is:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

That's `1` followed by 31 `0`s. Taking the negation according to [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is a two step process. 1) Change all `0`s to `1` and vice-versa:

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

then 2) add 1:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

So we get back the same value. Hence the infinite recursion.

If you MUST handle this case, here is one idea. Insert this just before the `n<0` test:

```
if (n==-2147483648) return 1/(x*pow(x,2147483647));
```

Obviously this is a hack for this one case. Ultimately your problem domain will determine the most elegant/general solution.

Comment: The expression `-n` actually has Undefined Behavior here.  But stack overflow is a common observed behavior, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick and nice reply. I changed it to 1/pow(x,abs(n));  But it still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: `abs` does not make your compiler any more capable of putting `1LL<<32` into an `int`.  You could do a special case test.

Comment: You are exceeding the size that can be represented in an `int`.

Comment: @user2994219 The answer has been updated to handle that one special case. Perhaps you can come up with a more elegant/general solution.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment and solution. Really appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

-2147483648 is hex 80000000 is the largest negative number, and one more than the largest positive one. So when n = -2147483648, there is no -n. The code will fail at the line

```
if(n<0) return 1/pow(x,-n);
```

This of course is a special case.

Comment: *might* fail.  Don't count on complaints about Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Given that we are told that the code fails, I do not think we need to be as cautious as that. We can just pretend to be programmers for once.

Comment: I see enough stackoverflow questions about "why didn't this unsafe code fail/crash/error" to be nervous about using any indicative.